# Avoid having a repeating task clutter the top of the agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Here is what I have:

[image]

My event is being repeated every week, however if I don't update the "original" date (2018-10-08) manually the event will stay on top of the agenda (`12 d. ago: EVENT weekly event`).

Is there a way to avoid having that on top of the agenda, by just repeating this event every monday (without specifying an original date) ? Something like `<Mon +1w>` (which doesn't work).

Comment: Remove the DEADLINE and leave it as a normal timestamp.

Comment: @Dan Thanks ! Didn't expect it to be that simple ..

Comment: Glad it helped!  I wrote a slightly more detailed answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items
marked
[`DEADLINE` and `SCHEDULED`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-scheduling.html) will
nag you with reminders that you haven't completed them on days
when the item is *not* scheduled to take place.

If you do not want these reminders to clutter your agenda view,
use
a
[normal timestamp](https://orgmode.org/manual/Creating-timestamps.html) instead.

Note that timestamps can have repeaters as well, but they will not
show up on the "wrong" days in your agenda view.  This feature is
useful for, say, a weekly meeting or class, such as:

```
* Weekly staff meeting
  <2018-09-05 +1w>
```